# Update specific object on ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, jquery-mobile, ionic-popup

I am interested in updating specific object on ng-class as my view is containing many objects out of which I want to apply update on specific object from the loop.

```
 <div>
            <div class="baseMap">
                <i ng-repeat="society in societyImage"
                   class="icon box"
                   ng-class="{ 'bigger': society.bigger }"
                   ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + society.imageUrl + '.png)', 'top':+ society.top, 'left':+ society.left}"
                        ng-click="showAlert($index)"></i>

            </div>

        </div>
```

///  Button Click index animateMapItem($index);

My JS function

```
var self = $scope;

    self.bigger = false;
    self.lightTheme = false;

    $scope.animateMapItem = function (index) {

        //self.bigger = !self.bigger;

        var listTitle = $scope.listItem[index].indicatorEn;

        var _societyObj = [];
        _societyObj = _.where($scope.societyImage, {'indicationEn':listTitle});

        $log.log(_societyObj);

        _societyObj.bigger = true;

    };
```

My CSS

```
.baseMap .icon {
        position: absolute;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        display: block;

    }

.box {
        -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
        transition:all linear 0.5s;
    }

    .box.bigger {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }
```

Now it is updating all item to bigger, where as I want to update specific item on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_societyObj` is a local object you cannot use it the view part in html. Make it as **scope object** then only you could use it the html view part. Change all local object used in the view part into $scope object. Otherwise Your code not works as per you expect

But the `$scope.animateMapItem` function always return true why???it does not make any sense

> $scope only be communicated between the controller and the view part
>   its two way binding

```
$scope.societyObj = [];
$scope.societyObj.bigger = true;
```

else return the _societyObj in the end of the function that should be

```
$scope.animateMapItem = function (index) {

        //self.bigger = !self.bigger;

        var listTitle = $scope.listItem[index].indicatorEn;

        var _societyObj = [];
        _societyObj = _.where($scope.societyImage, {'indicationEn':listTitle});

        $log.log(_societyObj);

        _societyObj.bigger = true;

        return _societyObj.bigger; // it always return true it doesn't make any sense

    };
```

In your html

```
<div class="baseMap">
                <i ng-repeat="society in societyImage"
                   class="icon box"
                   ng-class="{ 'bigger': animateMapItem($index) }"
                   ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + society.imageUrl + '.png)', 'top':+ society.top, 'left':+ society.left}"
                        ng-click="showAlert($index)"></i>

            </div>
```

Comment: I have achieved it from _societyObj = _.findWhere($scope.societyImage, {'indicationEn':listTitle});    from underscore framework, that returns same object but your suggestion is also good one.